# Calculate total, direct and indirect effects in SEM with Lavaan package R

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, effects

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to obtain in a table the decomposition of the effect of the variables of a SEM model. I have made the model with the sem function of the lavaan package, but I don't know how to obtain the total, direct and indirect effects using the same package.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:=` operator in lavaan syntax to define functions of estimated parameters, such as indirect and total effects.  There is an example of this on the lavaan website's tutorial section:

https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/mediation.html

The "new" parameters then appear in your `summary()` or `parameterEstimates()` output, along with (by default) a delta-method *SE* and associated normal-theory *z* test.

Comment: Thank you so much Terrence!